# Merge n number of .mp3(same bitrate) files using ffmpeg driver

Tags: php

I have 3 .mp3  files of 128 kbps. I want to merge these files using ffmpeg driver. Is this possible?

I have tried this code:

```
shell_exec("ffmpeg -i 1490103690_128_1.mp3 -i 1490103714_128_2.mp3 -i 1490103734_128_3.mp3 \
-filter_complex '[0:0][1:0][2:0]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[out]' \
-map '[out]' output.mp3");
```

Comment: What was the result of your Try? Is there an error / which error?

Comment: It is not giving me the merged output file. When I am using var_dump to see  if there is any error it is showing me NULL.

Actually I have already merged files by file_put_content but the problem is ID3 tags are giving me wrong information about the total duration of the generated merged file.

Comment: Have you tried to execute your command directly in the shell? It is not really a problem with PHP, more with ffmpeg. Have you had a look at https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate ?